# Magento 2 Main Configurable Products Duplicated in Order Info When Configurations are Ordered

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, orders, sales-order

In our Magento 2.2.7 store we have a number of Configurable Items, they are one Main item with a number of individual items as configurations.

When a customer orders them, they strangely appear as additional items in the order info with a price of £0.00 An example is below.

[image]

This is making the invoice of any order with a configurable product a bit difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this issue is a side effect of using an outdated version of the Extension M2E Pro (which we were using for migration purposes) as found at the following community forums.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8452

https://community.m2epro.com/topic/258-magento-2-issues-with-m2e-pro-need-help-frustrated/#comment-716

The issue was with a file found at the following location:

> app\code\Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\Order\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem.php

Once we had updated the module to it's latest version this problem stopped occurring.